# Как записать значение + ключ JSON из объекта в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, promise

Есть данные, записанные как объект. Нужно вывести в консоли значение + ключ в формате массива. 
Вот примерный вывод json, который нужно перевести в массив:

```
{userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
```

Код, который написал я, по каким-то причинам выводит только значения:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            const res = Object.keys(json).map((el) => {
                const resalit = (el, json[el])
                return resalit
            })
            return console.log(res)
    
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: Что значит "*вывести  в формате массива*" ?

Comment: Ваше решение вполне подойдет, но я бы ради интереса спросил, можно ли вывести эти данные так:[
{ключ + значение}
{ключ + значение}
]

Comment: можно.... просто надо строчку попровить в шаблоне  вместо `\`${val} → ${key}\``  писать строку `\`[ {${key} + ${val}} ]\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно?

```
const res = Object.entries(json).map(([key, val]) => {
    return [val, key]        
});
// можно сократить до const res = Object.entries(test).map(([key, val]) => ([val, key]))
// м.б. надо так? Object.entries(test).map(([key, val]) => (`${val} → ${key}`))


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так перебирайте ключи в объекте:

```js
const myObj = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false};

const res = [];
for (let x in myObj) {
  // Тут реализуйте ваше добавление данных в массив, я тут добавил значение + ключ
  res.push(`${myObj[x]} - ${x}`); // Строка
  //res.push([`${myObj[x]} - ${x}`]); // Строка как элемент массива
  //res.push([myObj[x], x]); // Массив значение ключ
  //res.push([x, myObj[x]]); // Массив ключ значение
  //res.push({[x]: myObj[x]}); // Объект ключ значение
  //res.push({[myObj[x]]: x}); // Объект значение ключ
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Думаю что нужна такая же структура как для `Map`...

Comment: @ΝNL993 Это какая?

Comment: `[[key, value], [key, value]]`

Comment: @ΝNL993 Возможно, однако в вопросе "Значение + ключ"... Варианты я привел, а далее пусть автор вопроса принимает решение, что и как ему выводить в своём коде )

Comment: Справедливо, но у вас минус :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Это тире, как разделитель, а не как математический знак )

Comment: Как заблагорассудиться :) (Ну и слова нужно писать, чтобы попасть в минимальный размер комментария)