# Как вывести значение объекта с помощью функции?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать, у меня есть объект `objectOfAnimals`. С помощью функции `funcOfAnimals`, которая принимает в параметры ключ объекта `objectOfAnimals`, должна выводить в консоль значение введенного ключа.

```js
const objectOfAnimals = {
    0: 'zebra',
    1: 'lion',
    2: 'giraffe',
    3: 'skunk',
    4: 'lama',
    5: 'dog',
    6: 'cat'
}
function funcOfAnimals (idOfAnimal) {
}
```

Comment: Зачем хранить животных в объекте, если можно в массиве?

Comment: @ΝNL993 так нужно по заданию

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Подсмотрите здесь, [как перебираются элементы из объекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474464/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-json-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2/1474468#1474468)

Comment: @SwaD спасибо за ответ, я перед тем как задать вопрос просматривал, мне нужно было выводить конкретное свойство а не все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const objectOfAnimals = {
    0: 'zebra',
    1: 'lion',
    2: 'giraffe',
    3: 'skunk',
    4: 'lama',
    5: 'dog',
    6: 'cat'
}

function funcOfAnimals (idOfAnimal) {
  return objectOfAnimals[idOfAnimal];
}

console.log(funcOfAnimals(5))
```

Comment: я только сообразил как сделать и увидел ваш ответ. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Smile Если это ответ на ваш вопрос, то это очень бессмысленная функция, т.к. можно вообще без функции, просто обратиться к самому объекту

Comment: @EzioMercer так указано в задание

Comment: @Smile бессмысленное задание :)