# Дан объект obj = {name: 'Петр', surname: 'Петров'}. Нужно создать массив из объектов вида:

Tags: javascript

arr = [
{
value: 'name',
label: 'Петр'
},
{
value: 'surname'
label: 'Петров'
}
]

Comment: [Возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474464/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-json-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2/1474468#1474468)

Comment: Что у вас не получается?
Помните, что **учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы
пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста,
отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при 
решении задачи (для этого нажмите [edit]). Например, приведите код,
который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0):

Для создания массива объектов вида, который вы указали, можно выполнить следующий код на JavaScript:

```js
const obj = {name: 'Петр', surname: 'Петров'};
const keys = Object.keys(obj);

const result = keys.map((key) => ({
  key: key,
  value: obj[key]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Этот код создаст массив объектов, где каждый объект будет иметь свойство key с именем ключа из исходного объекта и свойство value с соответствующим значением. В результате выполнения кода, вы получите что-то вроде:

```js
[
  { key: 'name', value: 'Петр' },
  { key: 'surname', value: 'Петров' }
]
```

Если я неправильно понял ваш вопрос, можете уточнить, что именно у вас возникают трудности?